# Not bind data after refresh the website in nopcommerce 4.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, drop-down-menu, nopcommerce

I bind products data in **nopcommerce** customer form admin panel in dropdownlist. Now, first I add the product and after that open the **customer** form at that time product binds **properly** in dropdownlist, while again I add the product and then open the customer form at that time new product is **not been shown** in dropdownlist. If I want to see that newly product in dropdownlist then I want to restart the website.

Now by **debug** I analysis that after one time run the **customer form** that products data is coming from **cache**, so its not showing that **newly** product in **dropdownlist**. I also check that how **nopcommerce** bind **vendor** list in customer form, but in that if newly vendor is **not** added then vendor list is showing from cache while if any **newly** vendor add then at that time newly vendor is also showing in dropdownlist without restart the website.

**For more clear, lets see the code**

**CustomerController**

```
public virtual IActionResult Create()
{
    if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCustomers))
        return AccessDeniedView();

    //prepare model
    var model = _customerModelFactory.PrepareCustomerModel(new CustomerModel(), null);

    return View(model);
}
```

**CustomerModelFactory**

```
public virtual CustomerModel PrepareCustomerModel(CustomerModel model, Customer customer, bool excludeProperties = false)
{
    ......
        
    //prepare available product

    _baseAdminModelFactory.PrepareProduct(model.AvailableProducts,
        defaultItemText: _localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Customers.Customers.Fields.Wastage.None"));
        
    return model;
}
```

**BaseAdminModelFactory**

```
public virtual void PrepareProduct(IList<SelectListItem> items, bool withSpecialDefaultItem = true, string defaultItemText = null)
{
    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));

    //prepare available products
    var availableProductItems = GetProductList();
    foreach (var productItem in availableProductItems)
    {
        items.Add(productItem);
    }

    //insert special item for the default value
    PrepareDefaultItem(items, withSpecialDefaultItem, defaultItemText);
}
```

**ProductMasterService**

```
public virtual IPagedList<ProductMaster> GetAllProduct(
            int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = int.MaxValue)
{
    var query = _productMasterRepository.Table;

    query = from ct in query
            select ct;

    query = query.Distinct().OrderByDescending(a => a.Id);

    var product = new PagedList<ProductMaster>(query, pageIndex, pageSize);

    return product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a new product using `IProductService.InsertProduct(Product product)` nopCommerce updates the collection cache, otherwise after inserting use `IEventPublisher.EntityInserted(product)`. This method fires updating a cache by CacheEventConsumer